# Error with 'NoneType Error' with SQLAlchemy:

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am a beginner in Flask. I have created an **sqlite database** defined by my **models.py** and I have **populated it with values**. I wanted to print all that is there in the back-end database-table: **line_info** using the search_var.html file. However, I am getting an error, kindly help

My **models.py**

```
from app  import db
class line_info(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    EUSOL_id = db.Column(db.VARCHAR (255), nullable=True)
    acc_id = db.Column(db.VARCHAR (255), nullable=True)
    acc_name=db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)
    reasons = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    genbank = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, EUSOL_id,acc_id,acc_name,reasons,genbank):
        self.EUSOL_id= EUSOL_id
        self.acc_id = acc_id
        self.acc_name = acc_name
        self.reasons = reasons
        self.genbank = genbank
```

I have added some dummy values from the Python shell to test:

```
from app import db, app
from app.models import line_info

l = line_info(EUSOL_id='abcdeg', acc_id='asgd', acc_name='tomato_name', reasons='wild', genbank='NA')
db.app = app
db.init_app(app)
db.create_all()
db.session.add(l)
db.session.commit() 
line_info.query.all()
[<line_info 1>]
```

My **routes.py**

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def search_func():
    line_info = None
    line_info = line_info.query.all()
    return render_template("search_var.html", line_info=line_info)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

My 'search_var.html'

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}Search{% endblock %}
{% block main %}

   <h1>Lines</h1>
    {% for line in line_info %}
      <p>{{line_info.id}}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/workstation1/flask_beta/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages     /flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/workstation1/flask_beta/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/workstation1/flask_beta/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/workstation1/flask_beta/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/workstation1/flask_beta/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/workstation1/flask_beta/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/workstation1/flask_beta/app/routes.py", line 9, in search_func
    line_info = line_info.query.all()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'query'
```

My directory tree

```
/flask_beta
|__/app
|     |__models.py
|     |__routes.py
|     |__/templates
|                |__search_var.html
|__app.db
|__run.py
|__config.py
```

Comment: You are setting `line_info = None` before executing `line_info.query.all()`

Comment: Also you are defining `Line_info`, then importing `line_info`

Comment: In future, **verify and test your question *before* posting**. Your typo in the class name made us make a few more assumptions here than were needed.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the typo

Comment: If you were using the same name for your model and your local variable then without the `line_info = None` you'd have gotten a `UnboundLocalError` exception, which is why you probably added that line in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't name your model `line_info` then use that same name for the list of instances. `line_info` is now a local variable, it can't also be a global name, which is why you get a `UnboundLocalError` exception when you remove your `line_info = None` line.

Use a *different name* for the `line_info.query.all()` result. You do not need to set anything to `None` first:

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app
from model import line_info

@app.route('/')
def search_func():
    lines = Line_info.query.all()
    return render_template("search_var.html", line_info=lines)
```

You can still use `line_info` in the template, although that's not really recommended either.

Instead, I recommend you rename your model to follow the [Python naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions); Use `CamelCase`, with uppercase initials, no `_` underscores:

```
class LineInfo(db.Model):
    # ...
```

Now it is much easier to distinguish from local variables.

Comment: Thanks, I have made the change from line_info to LineInfo. However, I am getting an error for importing models      "from models import LineInfo    
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'". Any clue ? I have posted the directory tree. Thanks

Comment: @Bitsy: I don't know what your structure is. I suspect you may want to use `from .models import ...` but your other imports suggest you are confused about packages vs. direct module imports then.

Comment: @Bitsy: if `app` is a package (`app/__init__.py`), then definitely use `from app.models import ...` or `from .models import ...`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of initializing line_info with None instead of import it from models file.

I hope that the following code will work.

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app 

from models import Line_info

@app.route('/')
def search_func():
    line_info = Line_info.query.all()
    return render_template("search_var.html", line_info=line_info)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Heads-up: the OP altered their post, the model is named `line_info` too.